# print an array that contains arr1's numbers which are not in arr2

Tags: c

I wrote a program that:

1. gets integers to arr1[3] by user's input
2. get another input - called max number.
3. arr2[3] gets random 3 numbers ranging from 0 to maxNumber.
   for e.g. if I enter number 4, then arr2[] will contain 3 integers from 0 to 3 (included).

4.Build arr3[3] which contains arr1[3] integers that **ARE NOT** in arr2[3] for e.g. if arr1[3] = 1 2 3, arr2[3] = 2 5 6, then arr3[3] = 1 3 *garbage here*

5. Print arr3[].

Weird problem: It prints only arr3[**0**] which is arr1[**2**]'s value, for some reason. Any suggestions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define N 3



void inputArr1(int arr1[]);
void maxValueC(int maxValue);
void inputArr2(int arr2[], int maxValue);
void inputArr3(int arr1[], int arr3[], int i, int count3);
void printArr3(int arr1[], int arr3[]);


void main()
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, count = 0, count3 = 0, maxValue = 0, arr1[N], arr2[N], arr3[N];

    inputArr1(arr1);

    printf("please enter maxValue: ");
    scanf("%d", &maxValue);
    while (maxValue <= 0)
    {
        maxValueC(maxValue);
    }

    srand(time(NULL));
    inputArr2(arr2, maxValue);

    printf("\nArray1: ");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", arr1[i]);
    }
    printf("\nArray2: ");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", arr2[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            if (arr1[i] != arr2[j])
            {
                count++;
            }
         }
    if (count == N)
        {
            inputArr3(arr1, arr3, i, count3);
        }
    count = 0;  
}
    printArr3(arr1, arr3);

    getch();
}

void inputArr1(int arr1[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0;i < N;i++)
    {
        printf("Please enter a digit[%d]: ",i);
        scanf("%d", &arr1[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void maxValueC(int maxValue)
{
    printf("Please enter a number that is bigger than 0!!!");
    scanf("%d", &maxValue);
}

void inputArr2(int arr2[], int maxValue)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        arr2[i] = rand() % (maxValue);
    }
}

void inputArr3(int arr1[], int arr3[], int i, int count3)
{
    arr3[count3] = arr1[i];
    count3++;
}

void printArr3(int arr3[])
{
    int i;
        printf("\nArray3: ");
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            printf("%d", arr3[i]);
        }
}
```

Comment: 1) What is the exactly Input and what should be the expected Output? 2) `void main(){}` should be at least `int main(void)}`. 3) `#include <time.h>` is missing also. 4) Here in `void printArr3(int arr1[], int arr3[])` are two arg, but `int arr1[]` is not used, why?

Comment: @Michi See (4.) , and arr1[] is there as an argument because I deleted some code, It's a check if arr1 == arr3. Anyways, I've edited the code without the argument. apart from it, all the code is there.

Comment: `while (maxValue <= 0)` this is wrong, Please type `-1` when you get asked `printf("Please enter a number that is bigger than 0!!!");` and then try a positive number greater then `0`

Comment: Let me know if I understand this. At **1** the numbers could be, `6,2,7`. At  **2** could be max number `10`. At **3** could be `5,1,9`. It is ok until here?

Comment: @Michi Yes. Thats right.

Comment: @Michi and `inputArr3()` seems wrong for the same reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `inputArr3()` you pass count3 as argument by value (it goes to your stack) and later you manipulate the value (in the stack) but your `count3` variable (defined in `main`) will never be altered.

You probably want to pass pointer to count3, for example:

```
void inputArr3(int arr1[], int arr3[], int i, int *count3)
{
...
  (*count3)++;
}
```

When you call the function you have to change it to as follows:

```
inputArr3(arr1, arr3, i, &count3);
```

Another problem is when you call `printArr3` - you call it with 2 arguments while it takes one. I suggest you change the call to `printArr3` as follows:

```
printArr3(arr3);
```

Do not forget to modify your function prototypes.

Comment: `*count3++;` means "dereference the pointer, throw the data away and increment the pointer" and it won't work well. Use `(*count3)++;`.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you need, because is hard to understand:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N 3


int main(void){
    int arr1[N];
    int arr2[N];
    int arr3[N];
    int found = 0;
    int a,b,i,j,k=0,t=0;
    int maxNumber = 8;

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    /* create Arr1 */
    for (a = 0; a < N; a++){
        arr1[a] = (rand() % maxNumber);
    }

    /* create Arr2 */
    for (a = 0; a < N; a++){
        arr2[a] = (rand() % maxNumber);
    }

    /* Print Arr1 */
    printf("Arr1\n");
    for (b = 0; b < N; b++){
        printf("%d ",arr1[b]);
    }

    /* Print Arr2 */
    printf("\nArr2\n");
    for (b = 0; b < N; b++){
        printf("%d ",arr2[b]);
    }

    /* create Arr3 */
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        for(j=0;j<N;j++){
            if(arr1[t] == arr2[j]){
                found++;
            }
        }

        if(!found){
            arr3[k]=arr1[t];
            k++;
        }

        found=0;
        t++;
    }

    /* Print Arr3 */
    printf("\nArr3\n");
    for(int u=0;u<k;u++){
        printf("%d ",arr3[u]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output1:

```
Arr1
0 4 2 
Arr2
6 1 2 
Arr3
0 4
```

Output2:

```
Arr1
6 0 1 
Arr2
0 7 5 
Arr3
6 1
```

Output3:

```
Arr1
7 2 7 
Arr2
7 5 6 
Arr3
2
```